# Cannot deploy a PHP project with nice .htaccess URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

Until yesterday, I only deployed my PHP projects with URL like `https: //myproject/mapage.php`. Today I have a project that includes a `.htaccess` file for rewriting URLs (without extension). Myproject contains only 3 main elements:

- a folder / app that contains all the application logic
- a / public
  folder which contains the image, js, css [...] files and above all
  the front controller (index.php)
- an `.htaccess` file with the following
  content:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that when I am on my local server, the project works well but when I deploy it on a subdomain of my server: `http://dev.example.org`, I receive the following message:

> **File not found.**

*** My server is configured on an unshared Debian Stretch dedicated server. We are using plesk obsidian 18 on this. By searching in the parameters of apache I was able to realize that there are virtualhosts configured on it.

The main domain and the subdomains are configured on another server and pointed on ip adress of our Debian Stretch Dédicated server.

Could someone help me deploy my project correctly?

Comment: You spelled ".htaccess" incorrectly as ".htacess" in 2 of 3 occurrences in your question before I edited it.  Make sure that that file name is spelled correctly where you are using it.

Comment: How are you configuring the virtual hosts on this server?  Is this your own server where you are creating them manually, or is this a shared server where you are using something like cPanel to create "add-on domains?"

Comment: This is an unshared Debian Stretch dedicated server. We are using plesk obsidian 18 on this. By searching in the parameters of apache I was able to realize that there are virtualhosts configured on it. I tried a lot of stuff but it still doesn't work. I really need help.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: How have you configured the domains with Plesk?

Answer (score 0):

First off I would make sure .htaccess is enabled in your Apache web server.
You need to open the configuration file for your site (ex. `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`) and make sure the `<Directory>` field for your site contains the line `AllowOverride All`

Secondly, you need to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled.
You can list enabled modules with `apachectl -M | sort`.
If it's disabled you can enable it by running `a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: These points are valid, but this is a blind guess. Instead of recommending specific changes to a setup you actually do not know it would make more sense to recommend to instead first find out what the actual issue is. If someone operates that http server himself (the exception) and actually does have access to the server configuration, then it would absolutely make sense to _first_ check the http server's error log file to find out what the actual issue is. And to only _then_ decide about what actions to take ...